# Custom sort compare function throws compile error

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-c++

A custom sort function in C++ on VC++ 2012 throws a compile error for the following code.

```
class Segmenter(){
public:
    vector<vector<float>> scanned;
    void modifyAndSort();
    bool sort_fn(const vector<float>&, const vector<float>&);
};

void Segmenter::modifyAndSort(){
    // Modify scanned
    // ...

    sort(scanned.begin(), scanned.end(), sort_fn);
}

bool Segmenter::sort_fn(const vector<float>& x, const vector<float>& y){
    return ((x[0]*x[1]) < (y[0]*y[1]));
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
Error   3   error C3867: 'Segmenter::sort_fn': function call missing argument list; use '&Segmenter::sort_fn' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: The error message gives  you the answer. Pass  `&sort_fn` in to sort () instead of `sort_fn` !

Comment: `class Segmenter(){` What is this?!

Comment: @spencer Almost. The hidden `this` parameter in all member functions will stil get him. Solution: `static` method.

Comment: @DeiDei probably the same thing as a `boolsort_fn`: A tyop.

Comment: @user4581301 You're right about needing `static`.

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
sort(scanned.begin(), scanned.end(), std::bind(&Segmenter::sort_fn, this));
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Don't forget to `#include <functional>`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways other ways to do this.

We can't just pass in a class method without binding the instance as Kerrek SB does in his answer. A method will have a hidden `this` parameter whether you use it or not.

In this case it looks like you use it not, so a static method is probably the easiest:

```
class Segmenter{
public:
    vector<vector<float>> scanned;
    void modifyAndSort();
    static bool sort_fn(const vector<float>&, const vector<float>&);
};

void Segmenter::modifyAndSort(){
    // Modify scanned
    // ...

    sort(scanned.begin(), scanned.end(), &sort_fn);
    //                                   ^ note: we need a pointer to the method.
}

bool Segmenter::sort_fn(const vector<float>& x, const vector<float>& y){
    return ((x[0]*x[1]) < (y[0]*y[1]));
}
```

Slightly more and less complicated at the same time option is everybody's close, personal friend the [Lambda Function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
class Segmenter
{
public:
    vector<vector<float>> scanned;
    void modifyAndSort();
};

void Segmenter::modifyAndSort()
{
    // Modify scanned
    // ...

    sort(scanned.begin(),
         scanned.end(),
         [](const vector<float>& x, const vector<float>& y)->bool
         {
             return ((x[0]*x[1]) < (y[0]*y[1]));
         });
}
```

Note: you will need two more Lambdas to get [an electric violin solo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqimpdBzTXA).

Comment: `sort(scanned.begin(), scanned.end(), &sort_fn); ` Does not work with a pointer to a member function, or a pointer to a normal function. But lambda should work I guess.

Comment: @VishwanathKR You have me there. My apologies. `sort_fn` would have to be `static` or a free function. Will fix. Wait, no it is `static`. Running up a test case to see what you ran into.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't work with static or free either.

Comment: @VishwanathKR What was the error you received? I'm unable to make my test case fail.

Comment: So it is interesting. First the way of just putting the function handle works for extremely simply custom sort functions. But fails with complex datastructures, I presume. Anyway the error I get is: 
`error C2664: 'bool (const std::vector<float,std::allocator<_Ty>> &,const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'const std::vector<float,std::allocator<_Ty>> &' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\algorithm 3070 1 bgsegm`

Comment: @VishwanathKR you changed the type of the inner vector from `float` to `int`. The function will have to likewise change. The class can also become a template to automate the change for you.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me where and how I am changing it?

Comment: @VishwanathKR I don't know, but that error message says your code called a function expecting a `vector` of `float` with a `vector` of `int`.

Comment: That is sth I cant figure out.

Answer (score 0):

std::bind() definitely works.

A simple method with just a struct.

```
void Segmenter::modifyAndSort(){
    // Modify scanned
    // ...

    sort(scanned.begin(), scanned.end(), Compare());
}

struct Compare {

    bool operator()(vector<int> x, vector<int> y) const { 
        return ((x[0]*x[1]) < (y[0]*y[1]));
    }
};
```